# Why is this loop happening out of order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code.  However, the final/result async callback is happening out of order.

```
function dogetcomp(sid, acb) {
    var comp = [];

    completed.find({
        sid: sid
    }).sort({
        date: -1
    }).limit(25).exec(function(err, comps) {
        for (var i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
            (function(cnt) {
                var d = {};
                async.series([function(cb) {
                    user.findOne({
                        uid: comps[cnt].uid
                    }, function(err, u) {
                        d.uname = u.name;
                        d.when = comps[cnt].date.toString();
                        cb();
                    });
                }, function(cb) {
                    rec.findOne({
                        type: comps[cnt].type
                    }, function(err, q) {
                        d.qname = q.name;
                        cb()
                    });
                }], function(res) {
                    console.log(cnt);
                    comp.push(d);
                    if (comp.length == comps.length) {
                        acb(null, comp);
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }
    });

}
```

This results in 1,2,3,0 being printed and the array being out of order.  Why is the first entry being processed last?  Is there a better way I could be doing this loop?

Comment: The normal for loop will not wait untill the functions inside are ready. You could better change this for loop to use the async library also. With async.eachSeries, then in the callback of async.series, call the callback for async.eachSeries then it will execute in nice order.

Comment: @LanderVanBreda please leave that as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal for loop will not wait untill the functions inside are ready. You could better change this for loop to use the async library also.

With async.eachSeries, then in the callback of async.series, call the callback for async.eachSeries then it will execute in nice order.

```
async.eachSeries([0,1,2,3],function(number,call){
  async.series([],function(res){call()});
},function(err){
    console.log('done');
})
```